# Spark - How to make a map serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to extract and transform from a big dataset some information which will be later consumed by other dataset.

Since the information to be consumed is always the same, and since it can be stored in a pair-value fashion, I was considering to just save this information in a look-at map which will be consumed by a udf, so I avoid several calls to the big dataset.

The problem is I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Is there any way to make the map serializable?

In case it is not possible, is there another way to store information in a look-at object in Spark?

Here is my code:

```
val cityTimeZone: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]  = Map("CEB" -> 8.0, "LGW" -> 0.0, "CPT" -> 2.0
, "MUC" -> 1.0, "SGN" -> 7.0, "BNE" -> 10.0, "DME" -> 3.0, "FJR" -> 4.0, "BAH" -> 3.0, "ARN" -> 1.0, "FCO" -> 1.0, "DUS" -> 1.0, "MRU" -> 4.0, "JFK" -> -5.0, "GLA" -> 0.0)

def getLocalHour = udf ((city:String, timeutc:Int) => {
    val timeOffset = cityTimeZone(city)
    val localtime = if((timeutc+timeOffset)%24 >= 0)(timeutc+timeOffset)%24 else ((timeutc+timeOffset)%24)*(-1)
    localtime
})

//$"dateutc" is a timestamp column like this: 2017-03-01 03:45:00 and $"city" a 3 letters code in capitals, like those in the map above

val newDF = DF
.select("dateutc","city")
.withColumn("utchour", hour($"dateutc"))
.withColumn("localhour", getLocalHour($"city", $"utchour"))

display(newDF)
```

Comment: `Map` with serializable key-values is serializable. That's not the problem, the actual problem is elsewhere. Maybe you attached the `Map` as a member variable of some non-serializable class. Please provide an [mcve] or at least a code snippet that shows how the map is created and how it is used in the `udf`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin you are right. I will add some code to update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member variable declaration

```
val cityTimeZone
```

in combination with

```
cityTimeZone(city)
```

inside the `udf` is problematic, because the latter is just a shortcut for

```
this.cityTimeZone(city)
```

where `this` is (presumably) some huge non-serializable object (probably because it contains a reference to a non-serializable spark context).

Make `getLocalHour` a `lazy val`, and move the map that is needed by the `udf` inside the definition of `getLocalHour` as a local variable, something along these lines:

```
lazy val getLocalHour = {
  val cityTimeZone: Map[String, Double] = Map("CEB" -> 8.0, "LGW" -> 0.0)
  udf ((city:String, timeutc:Int) => {
    val timeOffset = cityTimeZone(city)
    val localtime = if((timeutc+timeOffset)%24 >= 0)(timeutc+timeOffset)%24 else ((timeutc+timeOffset)%24)*(-1)
    localtime
  })
}
```

Alternatively, attach `cityTimeZone` to some *serializable* object (i.e. some object that does not contain references to any threads, sockets, spark contexts and all the other non-serializable stuff; e.g. package objects with utility methods and constants would be fine).

If the `udf` definition contains references to any other member variables, treat those accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that

Comment: what if we load cityTimeZone with the spark session? Should we do that within the udf?

Answer (score 0):

Seems people is still reaching this question. Andrey's answer helped me back them, but nowadays I can provide a more generic solution to the `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` is to don't declare variables in the driver as "global variables" to later access them in the executors.

So the mistake I was making on here was to declare the map `cityTimeZone` in the driver but later I was planning to use inside the udf, which computation will occur already in the executors.

Possible solutions would be to pass `cityTimeZone` as a third parameter in the udf `getLocalHour` or declaring that map inside `cityTimeZone`